# How to get the next() function to fire a second time with identical data?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm calling RxJs's **next()** function and passing it an object which is identical to the object which was just passed, but it's not firing for a second time. I was wondering if there's a way to force next() to fire even if the data it's passed is the same?

Is there another function I should be using?

Comment: Now that we have a description of the code, can we see the code please? :)

Comment: it should work, does not matter if value is the same

Answer (score 1):

Calling `.next` with the same data works just fine.

## Code

```ts
const subj = new Subject<number>();
subj.subscribe(console.log);
subj.next(1);
subj.next(1);
```

## Output

```html
1
1
```